# Navigation mobile side bar not disappearing when on desktop

Tags: html, css

The fa bars and times symbol isn't going away on desktop mode when the user has logged in but on mobile everything works fine with the output animation that it's supposed to do. On desktop it does not want to go away even when the display is set on none and it's not clickable and I've tried using !important or moving margins setting it on different displays and neither of them worked. Is there any way to solve this?

```css
.navbar .fa{
    display: none;
}


@media(max-width: 700px){
    .content h1{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.content h2{
    font-size: 15px;
}
.navbar ul li{
    display: block;
}
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    background: mediumpurple;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -300px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: 1s;
}
nav .fa{
    display: block !important;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.navbar ul{
    padding: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" class="logo"></a>
            <div class="navbar" id="navBar"><!--navlinks -->
                <i class="fa fa-times"onclick="hidemenu()"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="offers.php">Offers</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showmenu()"></i>
        </nav>
    </div>





<!-- javascript toggle menu -->
<script>
        var navBar = document.getElementById("navBar");
        function showmenu(){
            navBar.style.right="0";
        }
        function hidemenu(){
            navBar.style.right="-200px";
        }
    </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
      <script>
        AOS.init();
      </script>
      <script>
    let subMenu = document.getElementById("subMenu");

    function toggleMenu(){
        subMenu.classList.toggle("open-menu");
    }
            

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You want the navbar to appear and disappear on mobile but the navbar to be permanently there with no menu buttons on desktop?

Comment: Yes, the navbar to appear and disappear when it reaches 700px but to permanently  be there with no buttons on desktop.

Comment: See the answer below then :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear but I think I understand what you mean. The problem you have is everything in the media query for the mobile view (i.e. less than 700px wide). If you split out the css that styles everything for the desktop view then only apply the styles to show the buttons for the mobile view it'll work. Hopefully what I've coded will be self-evident but if not drop me a comment and I'll explain.

Run the code snippet and click on full page to shrink the window to see.

**note** I've had to add some specificity to the showmenu and hidemenu classes. On this site there seems to be a bit of an issue with other classes altering the fontawesome styling but ordinarily you wouldn't need them.

```js
var navBar = document.getElementById("navBar");

function showmenu() {
  navBar.classList.add('shownavbar');
}

function hidemenu() {
  navBar.classList.remove('shownavbar');
}
```

```css
/* Had to add some specificity here so it'll work in the StackOverflow preview pane */
nav .navbar .showmenu,
nav .hidemenu {
  display: none;
}

.content h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: block;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  background: mediumpurple;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: left 1s;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.hidemenu {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 30px;
}


/* Now introduce the buttons when in mobile mode */

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
  .navbar {
    left: -100%;
  }
  
/* Had to add some specificity here so it'll work in the StackOverflow preview pane */
nav .navbar .showmenu,
nav .hidemenu {
    display: block;
  }
  .shownavbar {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-xh6O/CkQoPOWDdYTDqeRdPCVd1SpvCA9XXcUnZS2FmJNp1coAFzvtCN9BmamE+4aHK8yyUHUSCcJHgXloTyT2A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<nav>
  <div class="navbar" id="navBar">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/50/50/" class="logo"></a>
    <!--navlinks -->
    <i class="fa fa-times hidemenu" onclick="hidemenu()"></i>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="offers.php">Offers</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.php">About us</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-bars showmenu" onclick="showmenu()"></i>
</nav>
```